# Input multiple string arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, arrays

I am just learning about arrays and my book barely explains how to input two-dimensional string arrays. Here is the code that my book recommends:

```
char lastName[6][50];

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  cout << "Enter candidates last name: ";
  cin.get(lastName[i], 50);
  cout << endl;
}


for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
  cout << lastName[i] << endl;
}
```

with this code I can only input one name and the rest of the program just repeats "Enter candidates last name: "

The other code that I tried was:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
 cout << "Enter candidates last name: ";
 cin >> lastName[i][50];
 cin.get(lastName[i], 50);
 cout << endl;
}

Same output code
```

This code lets me input the right amount of names but the first character of each name missing. Example "Joe" gives me "oe"

again, I am a beginner and I don't understand why its not working properly. Thanks!

Comment: it should be `j` instead of `i` in the line `cout << lastName[i] << endl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with mixing `cin` and `getline`. Formatted input (with the >> operator) and unformatted input (getline is an example) don't play well together. You should definitely read more about it. [Click here for more  explanation](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/365028/array-of-strings-input-problem).

Here is the solution to your problem.
`cin.ignore(1024, '\n');` is the key.

```
char lastName[6][50];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter candidates last name: ";
    cin.get(lastName[i], 50);
    cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
}
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    cout << lastName[j] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually was playing around with it and did cin >> lastName and it worked fine